# Как распознать присутствует на изображении текст или нет?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Задача такая, юзер фоткает или выбирает из галереи картинку. Моя задача, понять, что находится на изображении, фото документа (текст) или фото объекта (или просто какая-то картинка). В случае если на картинке документ (текст) - выдать одно сообщение, если нет - другое.
Интересует какая-либо библиотека или сервис. Желательно чтоб это распознавание работало локально на устройстве, если же это не возможно то допускаю какой-нибудь онлайн-сервис (хотя первое интереснее).

Answer (score 4):

[Google vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-labels), java api имеется